# Object still there after calling manual destructor for dynamically allocated object?

Tags: c++, oop, dynamic-memory-allocation, destructor

When two objects (one static and one dynamic) are created at same time then the destructor would delete them at same time (when object goes out of scope)?

Have a look at the below code block and its output:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

// Destructor (NO return type & NO input parameter)
class Hero {
public:
    int health;
    
    Hero() { // constructor
        cout << "constructor is called" << endl;
    }

    
    ~Hero() {// destructor
        cout << "destructor is called" << endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    Hero h1; // static allocation (automatically call destructor)

    Hero *h2 = new Hero; // dynamic allocation (manually call destructor)
    delete h2;

    cout << "Size (static)  : " << sizeof(h1) << endl;
    cout << "Size (dynamic) : " << sizeof(h2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

[image]

I have following two doubts:

1. Why Dynamic destructor is called first?
2. Why even after calling the destructor the size of the dynamically allocated object is non-zero?

Basic thing about destructor that I know is, for dynamically allocated objects we need to manually call the destructor while for statically allocated objects it is called automatically.

Comment: If you're on a 64-bit system the output you show doesn't match the code you show.

Comment: As for your question, the `sizeof` operator is a pure compile-time operation, it basically gets the size and hard-codes the result into the generated program.

Comment: Furthermore, using an object that doesn't exist anymore leads to *undefined behavior*. You should never do that. But that's not what's happening here though.

Comment: What is your point of confusion? You manually call the destructor of `h2` **while the `h1` object is still in scope**. The `h1` destructor is only called when it goes out of scope.

Comment: The pointer is still in scope even if what it pointed to has been deleted. And sizeof is showing your pointer has a size of 4 bytes (which kind of indicates a 32 bit build)

Answer (score 2):

> Why Dynamic destructor is called first?

Because you called it first.

`h1`'s destructor doesn't run until its lifetime ends, which is at the end of the main function's body (at the `}`).

> Why even after calling the destructor the size of the dynamically allocated object is non-zero?

You're checking the size of `Hero*`, which is always going to be the same, regardless of the value of the pointer (i.e. what it's *pointing to*).

This doesn't even have anything to do with destrcutors. See for yourself:

```cpp
Hero *h = nullptr;
cout << "sizeof(nullptr) " << sizeof(h) << endl; // Non-zero, probably 4 or 8.
```